# Serial Monitor not displaying anything

Tags: serial, c++, arduino-due, display

I have a very basic script that is supposed to display something to the serial monitor but no matter what I try the serial monitor won't display anything...I;ve watched about 5 tutorials now and each one has failed to display anything. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
char rx_byte;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() > 0){
    rx_byte = Serial.read();
    Serial.print("You typed: ");
    Serial.println(rx_byte);
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you typing anything into the serial monitor? What baud rate is the serial monitor set to?

Comment: I'm typing just the number 1 and 0, according to the tutorial I watched that should turn the LED on/off. The baud rate is set the same as what is in my code.

Comment: `I'm typing just the number 1 and 0` - and then you pressed the *Send* button? Please add `Serial.println ("Hello, world");` after the `Serial.begin` line and see if that appears in the serial monitor.

Comment: Yes then I pressed the send button. I tried putting that line in after Serial.begin and still nothing...

Comment: Well, solve that first. No point typing and pressing Send if nothing appears. What Arduino do you have? What version of the IDE?

Comment: I've got the arduino due, I can't find the version of the IDE, where would I find it? (I'm using osx)

Comment: Found it, its 1.6.6

Comment: `I've got the arduino due` - you might have mentioned that earlier. That has two USB ports. Which one are you using?

Comment: The one closest to the reset button, I believe its the native...

Comment: See: [Getting started with the Arduino Due](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoDue)

Comment: Interesting, I'll try the programming port then!

Comment: Bingo, that did it, working perfectly now!

Comment: I've summarized this discussion, and my findings, in a new answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which one are you using?
>
> The one closest to the reset button, I believe its the native...

This is more confusing than I realized. The Due has two ports:

[image: Due ports]

---

### Programming port

For programming, the programming port is easiest to use. **And** you can "talk" to the serial port using `Serial`, like this:

```
void setup ()
  {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ("Hello, world!");
  }  // end of setup

void loop ()
  {
  }  // end of loop
```

---

### Native USB port

This lets you emulate USB devices (eg. keyboard, mice). However if you want to use it for Serial communications you need to use a different class `SerialUSB` like this:

```
void setup ()
  {
  SerialUSB.begin(115200);
  while (!SerialUSB) ; // wait for it to become ready
  SerialUSB.println ("Starting ...");
  }  // end of setup

unsigned long i;

void loop ()
  {
  SerialUSB.print ("Hello, world! Count = ");
  SerialUSB.println (++i);
  delay (1000);
  }  // end of loop
```

It also helps to wait for the serial port to become ready, as I did in `setup`. Otherwise you may miss the first 10 lines or so of serial output.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the baud rate at the right bottom corner of the serial monitor to 115200 which you have assigned initially.
I have tested it  and
It doesn't matter if its int/char

Comment: I have done that, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the line `char rx_byte;` with `int rx_byte=0;`. Use `Serial.println(rx_byte,DEC);`

```
int rx_byte=0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() > 0){
    rx_byte = Serial.read();
    Serial.print("You typed: ");
    Serial.println(rx_byte,DEC);
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: Same again, nothing...